# Convert first value from 0 to 1 based on group and mask columns in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert the first occurrence of 0 to 1 in a column in a Pandas Dataframe. The Column in question contains 1, 0 and null values. The sample data is as follows:

| mask_col | categorical_col | target_col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TRUE | A | 1 |
| TRUE | A | 1 |
| FALSE | A |  |
| TRUE | A | 0 |
| FALSE | A |  |
| TRUE | A | 0 |
| TRUE | B | 1 |
| FALSE | B |  |
| FALSE | B |  |
| FALSE | B |  |
| TRUE | B | 0 |
| FALSE | B |  |

I want row 4 and 11 to change to 1 and keep row 6 as 0.

How do I do this?

Comment: What exactly is the logic? All stretches of `True` up to the second are 1, others are 0?

Comment: I am imaging using the categorial as a groupby column and then combined with the True value of the mask only change the first occurrence of 0 to 1 in each of the groups

Comment: So you literally want the first 0 per group? the values of `mask_col` or the other values in `target_col` don't matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For set first `0` per groups by `categorical_col` use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) with compare by `0` for set `1`:

```
df.loc[df['target_col'].eq(0).groupby(df['categorical_col']).idxmax(), 'target_col'] = 1
print (df)
    mask_col categorical_col  target_col
0       True               A         1.0
1       True               A         1.0
2      False               A         NaN
3       True               A         1.0
4      False               A         NaN
5       True               A         0.0
6       True               B         1.0
7      False               B         NaN
8      False               B         NaN
9      False               B         NaN
10      True               B         1.0
11     False               B         NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic is not fully clear, so here are two options:

##### option 1

Considering the stretches of `True` per group of `categorical_col` and assuming you want the first `N` stretches (here N=2) as `1`, you can use a custom [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
vals = (df.groupby('categorical_col', group_keys=False)['mask_col']
          .apply(lambda s: s.ne(s.shift())[s].cumsum())
       )

df.loc[vals[vals.le(2)].index, 'target_col'] = 1
```

##### option 2

If you literally want to match only the first `0` per group and replace it with `1`, you can slice only the 0s and get the first value's index with [`groupby.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html):

```
df.loc[df['target_col'].eq(0).groupby(df['categorical_col']).idxmax(), 'target_col'] = 1

# variant with idxmin
idx = df[df['target_col'].eq(0)].groupby(df['categorical_col'])['mask_col'].idxmin()
df.loc[idx, 'target_col'] = 1
```

Output:

```
    mask_col categorical_col  target_col
0       True               A         1.0
1       True               A         1.0
2      False               A         NaN
3       True               A         1.0
4      False               A         NaN
5       True               A         0.0
6       True               B         1.0
7      False               B         NaN
8      False               B         NaN
9      False               B         NaN
10      True               B         1.0
11     False               B         NaN
```

Comment: Second solution not working - need `idxmax` - check my answer.

Comment: @jezrael oh you're right silly me, I had a slightly different approach in mind and refactored it while posting

Comment: I am now confused, why change your answer by `df.loc[df['target_col'].eq(0).groupby(df['categorical_col']).idxmax(), 'target_col'] = 1` which is already posted and accepted in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the first zero occurrence for each category with the following loop:

```
for category in df['categorical_col'].unique():
    index = df[(df['categorical_col'] == category) &
               (df['target_col'] == 0)].index[0]
    df.loc[index, 'target_col'] = 1
```